# Comparing predictions from multilevel meta-regression model

Tags: r, meta-regression

I'm using the `metafor` package in R to perform a multi-level meta-regression. I did not supply a variance-covariance matrix to the `rma.mv()` function as I don't have this data.

I want to compare pairs of predictions from this model (at specific levels of the covariates) and test if they are statistically significantly different from one another.

Based on [this page](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates), I'm using a Wald-type test. I've grabbed the predicted mean and standard error values using `predict.rma` and then generated a p-value using:

```
wald_z <- (prediction2 - prediction1)/sqrt(se2^2 + se1^2)    
2*pnorm(-abs(wald_z)
```

But I'm not sure if this is a valid approach. Is this appropriate? Is there a better way to make these comparisons? I also wondered if I should just compare the confidence intervals and whether they overlap, but this seems overly simplistic.

Comment: You might get a better response on the R meta-analysis mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//